# LINQ select (using entity framework)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Having the following tables:

- Messages

[image]

---

- MessageThread

[image]

---

- MessageThreadParticipant

[image]

---

- MessageReadState

[image]

I need to get the following using LINQ (I'm using EF4 so these have knowledge of each other).

1) Get a list of TOP 1 message (from a thread), also marking if this is a new message for a given LoginId

so for example (loginId 118)

Should display a list of only 1 item with a messageID: 368 (because I participate in that conversation). Also, I need to know that this is a NEW message for LoginId 118 because MessageReadState doesn't not have an entry for me.

example2: (Login 116)
should list 4 threads because I participate in threadId's (24, 25, 26,27). With a newest message from each thread.

EDIT:
EF (if anyone using the same structure)
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question about LINQ (to Entities) is difficult to answer if you don't show your entities with their navigation properties. But assuming classes and navigation properties have everything you need to perform such a query I would try this:

```
var result = context.MessageThreadParticipants
    .Where(mtp => mtp.LoginId == givenLoginId)
    .Select(mtp => new
    {
        MessageThread = mtp.MessageThread,
        NewestMessage = mtp.MessageThread.Messages
           .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreateDate)
           .Select(m => new
           {
               Message = m,
               HasBeenRead = m.MessageReadStates
                   .Any(mrs => mrs.LoginId == givenLoginId)
           })
           .FirstOrDefault(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

So, entity `MessageThreadParticipant` must have a `MessageThread` property. Entity `MessageThread` must have a `Messages` collection and entity `Message` must have a `MessageReadStates` collection.

`result` is then a collection of anonymous objects. Every object contains:

- `MessageThread` : the thread the user with `givenLoginId` participates in
- `NewestMessage.Message` : the newest message in this thread
- `NewestMessage.HasBeenRead` : a boolean flag if the newest message has been read

Comment: Thank you Slauma for you help. I actually tried several queries but I was stuck on the grouping (trying joins and groupjoins) but that didn't work. Your codes works great. exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot!.